# Calling variables with pointers in a typedef

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

Hello i know a bit about pointers in C but the problem I am running into is how to access variables in an this typedef enum.

The structure is defined as:

```
typedef enum {
ZERO = (uint8_t) 0, ONE = (uint8_t) 1
} BIT;

typedef BIT lc3_word_t[16];
```

and the method that is calling it is:

```
word_not(lc3_word_t *R, lc3_word_t *A) {

/*int i;
for (i=0;i<16;i++){
printf("Current i is: '%d' and the value is: '%d' \n", i, *A[i]);
//lc3_word_t a_value = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}; // 13
}
*/

}
```

The commented out section is what I have been trying along with some other variations that were introduced in this post: [Understanding C: Pointers and Structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148512/understanding-c-pointers-and-structs)

If anyone could help me get this it would be greatly appreciated.
THanks

Comment: The casts on the values 0 and 1 in the `enum` don't do you any good.  An enumeration constant is always of type `int` -- and the values start from 0 by default.  You might as well just write `typedef enum { ZERO, ONE } BIT;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use (*A)[i], not *A[i].