# Understanding pointers to structs

Tags: c

I am making structs of pointers which point to structs. I've been googling like a madman and I can't figure out why the printf statement below gives different memory addresses. Could somebody explain this to me?

```
struct board_piece {
   board_piece* next;
   board_piece* prev;
} board_piece;

main (int argc, char *argv []) {

  board_piece *newPiece = malloc (sizeof (board_piece));
  board_piece *newPiece2 = malloc (sizeof (board_piece));
  newPiece->next = newPiece2;
  printf("%x, %x",  newPiece->next, newPiece2); //Why aren't these the same address?
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding C: Pointers and Structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148512/understanding-c-pointers-and-structs)

Comment: At first glance, I agree with you.  They should be the same.  Also, as they are dynamically allocated, I don't think the compiler will be optimizing them out.  Besides the %p option mentioned below, I would suggest looking at your values in a debugger to see when it says.

Comment: The code you posted is invalid. You've defined a type called `struct board_piece`, not `board_piece`. You define `board_piece` as an object name, but then use it as a type name. `main` should be defined with a return type of `int`. You're missing the required `#include` directives for `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>`. Please post actual copy-and-pasted code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `%p` as your format specifier.  You might be on a platform where pointers and integers are different sizes.

Comment: -1. Even if pointers and integers were not the same size, the value printed should be the same.

Comment: @Gonzalo: It depends on the calling conventions for variadic functions.  He might be seeing the upper and lower half of a 64-bit pointer.

Comment: Damn it. How do I undo the -1? :)... Done!

Comment: `%p` expects a `void *`. You should cast that.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your code doesn't compile due to a few errors. You need to declare your type before you can use it in the struct; and you are declaring a global variable, `board_piece`, not a type, because you didn't use `typedef`. Are you sure that the code you are running is actually the code that you think it is?

Second, as Ben Jackson points out, you should use `%p` for pointers, because pointers can be wider than integers. If you use `%x` which indicates an integer, and pass a pointer in, `printf()` may look in the wrong place for the value.

The following works for me, printing out the same value for both pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct board_piece board_piece;

struct board_piece {
   board_piece* next;
   board_piece* prev;
};

int main () {

  board_piece *newPiece = malloc (sizeof (board_piece));
  board_piece *newPiece2 = malloc (sizeof (board_piece));
  newPiece->next = newPiece2;
  printf("%p, %p",  newPiece->next, newPiece2); //Why aren't these the same address?

  return 0;
}
```

I would recommend compiling with warnings enabled, and treated as errors. If you are using GCC or Clang, I generally recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`; there is likely to be an equivalent set of options for MSVC. Note that when doing so, you need to fix a few more warnings, such as no return type declared for `main` and unused arguments. I've fixed those problems in the above, so it compiles without warnings.